# SharePoint 2013 - Serach not working randomly

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

It has been quite some time now since I'm struggling with a strange issue on a SharePoint 2013 farm.
The search is randomly not working on some PCs/servers although these same machines are located in the same subnet. 
When searching for any type of content you get an error message.

Sorry something went wrong.
Access is denied.

Correlation ID : 507f6c9e-7ef8-30c4-988f-2f5998536d08

Upon checking the packets using Fiddler, I have seen an error (401 Untheorized).
The ULS logs don't show any thing such as the correlation ID that pops up when you try to serach.

It's also not possible to access the "result source" or the "result types" in the site collection settings and it will return with a error.

sorry, an error occurred.

Correlation ID : b37f6c9e-ce6d-30c4-988f-233598cea61f

Anyone has an idea please?